# How to use SqueezeNet in CNTK?

Tags: cntk

I am a CNTK user.  I use AlexNet but would like a more compact NN -- so SqueezeNet seems to be of interest.  Or does someone have some other suggestion? How do CNTK users deploy when size matters?  Does somebody have a CNTK implementation of SqueezeNet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new `ONNX model` format now has several pretrained vision models, including one for [`SqueezeNet`](https://github.com/onnx/models/tree/master/squeezenet). You can download the model and load it into CNTK:

```
import cntk as C
z = C.Function.load(<path of your ONNX model>, format=C.ModelFormat.ONNX)
```

You can find tutorials for importing/exporting `ONNX models` in CNTK [here](https://github.com/onnx/tutorials/blob/master/tutorials/OnnxCntkImport.ipynb).

Answer (score 0):

SqueezeNet is a good choice for a small network with the possibility of a good accuracy. Take a look at [DSDSqueezeNet](https://github.com/DeepScale/SqueezeNet) for even better accuracy.
However, if it does not need to be as small as SqueezeNet you also could take a look at [MobileNet](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/nets/mobilenet_v1.md) or [NasNet Mobile](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/slim/nets/nasnet). These networks may be bigger, but they provide state of the art performance in the task of image classification.

Unfortunately, I do not have an CNTK implementation of SqueezeNet, but maybe a pretrained CNTK model, which you can reuse and finetune using [Transfer Learning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cognitive-toolkit/Build-your-own-image-classifier-using-Transfer-Learning) is all what you are looking for. In this case I can recommend you [MMdnn](https://github.com/Microsoft/MMdnn), a conversion tool, which allows to convert a existing pretrained Caffe network to the CNTK model format. In [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/MMdnn/issues/48) you can find a step by step guide for SqueezeNet.

I would not know of a method for especially small deployment, but you have basically two choices when it comes to saving your model: The standard CNTK model format and the new [ONNX format](https://github.com/onnx/onnx) which CNTK [is going to support or does already.](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/blob/master/README.md) Till now, I could not try it myself, but maybe it offers a smaller size for the same network.
Since the CNTK model format is already saving the model in binary, I would not expect high improvements anyway, for any format. Anyway, compressing the model definitively could be an option, if size is very important.